# Is there a way in MongoMapper to achieve similar behavior as AR's includes method?

Tags: ruby, mongomapper, eager-loading

Is there a feature equivalent in MongoMapper to this:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :x
  scope :with_x, includes(:x)
end
```

When running Model.with_x, this avoids N queries to X.
Is there a similar feature in MongoMapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it's a `belongs_to` relationship, you can turn on the [identity map](http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/identity-map.html) and run two queries, once for your main documents and then one for all the associated documents. That's the best you can do since Mongo doesn't support joins.

```
class Comment
  include MongoMapper::Document
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  include MongoMapper::Document
  plugin MongoMapper::Plugins::IdentityMap
end

@comments = my_post.comments                # query 1
users = User.find(@comments.map(&:user_id)) # query 2

@comments.each do |comment|
  comment.user.name # user pulled from identity map, no query fired
end
```

(Mongoid has a [syntax for eager loading](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#includes), but it works basically the same way.)

Comment: Also, if it's a Rails app with a lot of objects, it may be GC bound and so eager loading will reduce queries but your response time may not improve much. On one of our apps with ~400 objects being loaded, this eager loading only bought us a ~10% improvement in request response time. Disabling the GC for the duration of that request bought us another 35%.