# MongoMapper include when querying to "greedy-load" data and avoid multiple DB hits?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

ActiveRecord has this convenient feature to eager load data in a single request so as to avoid hitting the database multiple times:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

I want to do this with MongoMapper - there is a similar post on SO about it here:

[Is there a way in MongoMapper to achieve similar behavior as AR's includes method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894784/is-there-a-way-in-mongomapper-to-achieve-similar-behavior-as-ars-includes-metho)

But the example given there doesn't make sense to me (and when I adapt the code to my own - it doesn't work).

I can get the mapping part to function, where I end up with a big chunky object that includes all the customers for the jobs that I'm loading.

But when I go to call the customer name out of job like :

job.customer.first_name

It of course fires off a DB query.

The link to the other SO post says we should do two queries:

```
@allJobs = Job.where(:environment => id)
customer = Customer.find(@allJobs.map(&:customer_id))
```

And Jobs belongs_to Customer in my case.

Right away I couldn't tell why storing the map query into "customer" would help @allJobs avoid the DB hit (and it doesn't).

I end up with the map:

```
MONGODB (5.5ms) test_development['customers'].find({:_id=>{:$in=>[BSON::ObjectId('5386a07502acd80008000012'), BSON::ObjectId('53653443c956aa0012000098'), BSON::ObjectId('53877d645c794800140000bd'), BSON::ObjectId('53853c98344f57000e000027'), BSON::ObjectId('53864bea344f57461e000027'), BSON::ObjectId('5386652994a641000800011d'), BSON::ObjectId('5387769e5c794800080000a1'), BSON::ObjectId('53483e87ed4fe900080000af'), BSON::ObjectId('536163329532de000b000007'), BSON::ObjectId('537f9beb375a43000c0000fc'), BSON::ObjectId('5384ecaa8c8cea00140000c6'), BSON::ObjectId('538641d994a64100080000d8'), BSON::ObjectId('53867ed7344f574f0b00005a'), BSON::ObjectId('538628c894a64100080000ac'), BSON::ObjectId('538537e9344f57000e00000e'), BSON::ObjectId('5386467394a641415800004f'), BSON::ObjectId('538786ae5c794800080000c5'), BSON::ObjectId('53852d0b8c8cea5a0300002d'), BSON::ObjectId('538635b694a641415800001a'), BSON::ObjectId('5387871c02acd8000f0000ce'), BSON::ObjectId('5386337d94a64100080000bb'), BSON::ObjectId('5386254a344f573cbc00002d'), BSON::ObjectId('5386502d94a641441b000059'), BSON::ObjectId('5352d3acdf3e6d0968000089'), BSON::ObjectId('53863986344f57000b0000e3'), BSON::ObjectId('537f925ab8267d00080000cb'), BSON::ObjectId('53863f4794a6414158000037'), BSON::ObjectId('5384ed388c8cea00140000ca'), BSON::ObjectId('5384f2cf2d84a1000b0000bf'), BSON::ObjectId('538632cd344f57000b0000c0'), BSON::ObjectId('53850b362d84a10011000157'), BSON::ObjectId('53861d6194a641000b0000af'), BSON::ObjectId('5385093f2d84a10015000141'), BSON::ObjectId('5386214c94a6413e10000006'), BSON::ObjectId('5386372794a6413e1000005d'), BSON::ObjectId('53866a52344f574ee9000043'), BSON::ObjectId('538663c594a64141580000af'), BSON::ObjectId('5386384894a6413e10000067'), BSON::ObjectId('53867682344f574ee900005d'), BSON::ObjectId('5387757c5c794800140000a8'), BSON::ObjectId('538549f894a6410017000025'), BSON::ObjectId('53854c4694a641001700002a'), BSON::ObjectId('538501b72d84a1447d000070'), BSON::ObjectId('538537ff344f570008000002'), BSON::ObjectId('537e8af9b8267d000e000021'), BSON::ObjectId('5384cc022d84a10011000093'), BSON::ObjectId('53853213344f570011000004'), BSON::ObjectId('52c24eab3f5010001100012a'), BSON::ObjectId('537bf10a9e46264fa7000069'), BSON::ObjectId('5384cd9f8c8cea001400007b')]}})
```

As well as hitting the DB 50 times when I call job.customer.first_name in the view (paginated to 50 results)

How can I avoid the N queries and correctly eagerly load the customers for these jobs?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution - this is not the best solution or even the solution to the exact question posed.  But if anyone comes along searching Google - they will at least find some guidance.

In the view:

```
<% c = @customers.find { |c| c['_id'] == job.customer_id }; if c %> <%= c.first_name + " " + c.last_name %> <% else %> N/A <% end %>
```

In the controller:

```
@customers = Customer.find(@allJobs.map(&:customer_id))
```

I *hate* having the Ruby code in the view.  I could have essentially inserted some new key/value into the Jobs object by doing an each do |c| c.customer_name = @customers.find ... in the controller or even in the class - but it really didn't matter, because any way you slice it it's not the eager loading documented in the MongoMapper plugin for relationship mapping.  It just doesn't appear to work.

In this solution - we just grab all the customers into a single object with the map statement and only hit the DB twice - once for Jobs and once for Customers - but then we have to increase the view rendering by going through the @customers object for each job.

When I measured it - this method cut nearly 100 ms off page rendering time, and it's a better solution than hitting the DB 50 times per page because the DB is over at MongoLab and the app is on Heroku, so any slowdown between them could contribute to much longer load times.  At least we avoid clogging up the pipe between app and DB servers, if not following perfect Ruby practices.